# How to insert a background image in only one page using latex?

Tags: svg, background, latex

I am writing a document and I need to insert a background on only the third page (which is sort of a second cover of the document), but I have troubles in doing it, since all I tried resulted in the image not appearing or a background with the word "Draft".

```
\documentclass[epsfig,a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,outer=1.5cm,inner=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % layout setting
\usepackage{titlesec} % custom setup title of chanpter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inkscapeformat=pdf]{svg}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{eso-pic}  

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includesvg[width=\paperwidth]{logo.svg}
\vfill
}}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\input{front}
\cleardoublepage
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-3]
\cleardoublepage
```

With this code the result is the "Draft" word appearing as the background image. I also tried to use a png image, thinking that the svg conversion could be the problem, but apparently it's not since using a png image results in the same "Draft" word appearing in the background.

EDIT: As a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[epsfig,a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,outer=1.5cm,inner=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % layout setting
\usepackage{titlesec} % custom setup title of chanpter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inkscapeformat=pdf]{svg}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includesvg[width=\paperwidth]{logo.png}
\vfill
}}}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Windows;
\singlespacing

\begin{document}

  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \cleardoublepage
  \BgThispage
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \cleardoublepage
 
\end{document}
```

The image, saved as logo is found at the following [Link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/thumb/e/e4/Sigillo_Universit%C3%A0_di_Trento.svg/1024px-Sigillo_Universit%C3%A0_di_Trento.svg.png)

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the edit should now help more

Comment: We can't compile your example. You are including all kinds of files we don't have access to. Are you sure you can't reproduce the problem without them?

Comment: Now it should be possible to compile, I changed the svg file with the png, since it shows the same error, including a link to save the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer need all these `eso-pic` and `background` package. Latex now has a build in support for adding stuff to the background via its hook mechanism:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,outer=1.5cm,inner=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % layout setting
\usepackage{titlesec} % custom setup title of chanpter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inkscapeformat=pdf]{svg}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Windows;
\singlespacing

\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at (current page.center) {
    \includegraphics[width=16cm]{example-image-duck}
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \cleardoublepage
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \cleardoublepage
 
\end{document}
```

[image]